# Invalid literal python fortune teller

Tags: python

```
def My_Fortune():
    color = int(input("Select a Color: red, blue, yellow, or green: "))
    if color == "red":
        number = int(input("Select a number: 1, 3, 5, or 7: "))
        if number == 1:
            print("You will be forever alone")
        elif number == 3:
            print("You will get very lucky very soon")
        elif number == 5:
            print("The police will be searching for you shortly")
        elif number == 7:
            print("You will get you dream job")
        else:
            print("Invalid Request")
```

Im getting invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'red'

Comment: The answers below me are correct. I'd add though that I strongly recommend you to use a dictionary instead of all the "if" statements.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to converting your color input 'red' to an int:

```
color = int(input("Select a Color: red, blue, yellow, or green: "))
```

Change it to

```
color = input("Select a Color: red, blue, yellow, or green: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are. A line above, you are converting the input into an `int` value, then you are using it as a `str`. Solution: don't convert the value to `int`.